# How not to close Chakra Modal when clicking on overlay background but still interact with background elements

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

Is it possible to interact with background elements with an open modal? The modal should be always open before I not clicking the Close Button.

```
export default PhoneNumberInput;
function BasicUsage() {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure()

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={onOpen}>Open Modal</Button>

      <Modal blockScrollOnMount={false} isOpen={isOpen} onClose={onClose}>
        <ModalOverlay />
        <ModalContent>
          <ModalHeader>Modal Title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalCloseButton />
          <ModalBody>
            <Text fontWeight='bold' mb='1rem'>
              You can scroll the content behind the modal
            </Text>
            <Lorem count={2} />
          </ModalBody>

          <ModalFooter>
            <Button colorScheme='blue' mr={3} onClick={onClose}>
              Close
            </Button>
            <Button variant='ghost'>Secondary Action</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </ModalContent>
      </Modal>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to achieve the result:

1. Use `blockScrollOnMount={false}` to let users scroll the content behind the Modal.
2. Use the css property `pointer-events` to prevent the modal-container from catching the pointer events (e.g. clicking things, marking text).
3. Remove ModalOverlay (or adapt to be more transparent)

[`mdn: pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

> [...] property sets under what circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the target of pointer events.

```
<Modal
  blockScrollOnMount={false}
>    
  <ModalOverlay pointerEvents="none" />
  <ModalContent
    pointerEvents="all"
    containerProps={{ pointerEvents: "none" }}
  >
```